# Juggler animation isn't effected by fps rate?

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

i m recently building a small game and using starling for first time - i have a face which is moving from left to right and then right to left - and below is the tube head which is also moving with respect to face - 
i m animating face by juggler method and moving tube by simple playing with x-axis (isn't it bad practice :p )

so problem is when fps < 30 tube movement slows down but face animating in its regular speed - so i lost co-ordination there - Any solution?
will be appriciated
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Starling Juggler animates using time, so it's fps independent (it will render what it can, but the anim is going to last as long as you requested, no more, no less). If you anim other objects based on ENTERFRAME events, and use events as a timer (instead of the actual time passed between frames), you'll easily lose synchronization, since in real life fps can vary wildly. Relying on it for animation is probably not advisable.

Anyways, I urge you to embrace the Juggler for all your animating needs, its tweens are awesome.